# How to find if a JavaScript code is running on it's own domain?

Tags: javascript, dns, analytics

I work on an analytics website and I want to put an analyzer code specific for each website. Is it possible to check if a user uses his own JavaScript code?

Is it necessary and enough to put a customer code in each JavaScript and check it with domain name to be sure about this? Or do I need something like session or so?

Comment: Have you not looked at what Google does??

Comment: Uses their own js code to do what?  Most websites today have at least some javscript code.  I agree with epascarello.  Look at what Google Analytics and StatCounter do to see how they work.  No reason to reinvent the wheel.  You can sign up for each one free and embed them in your own web page and then study how they are configured and how they work.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the `src` attribute of the script tags:

```
// returns all script tags
    var all_script_tags = document.getElementsByTagName("script"); 
// returns the src attribute of the first script 
    var src_script = all_script_tags[0].src; // tag
```

Comment: What's with the `.src; tag` ?